Is there a way to get program id of CPI call?
I am calling a solana program A from solana program B using cpi invokes. Is there a way to get the program id of program B on program A or a way to get the cpi is invoked?

The information about the caller program is not provided to a callee program during CPI, but there's a workaround. You could verify the caller program id by:

including the caller program id as instruction data
requiring any caller program to sign with a PDA

Then your program needs to check that the PDA address is correctly derived based on the instruction data, and that the account is provided as a signer to your program.

Hi I am using pda seeds to sign the transaction, also marked the pda account of target program as signer but getting error Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

Can you elaborate the second point?

Certainly! Let's assume that your program takes the caller program id as instruction data, and there's also a PDA provided to your program. You would check that the PDA is a signer, and that its address is equal to find_program_address(["some_seed_required_by_your_program"], program_id_in_instruction_data)

I got it but my doubt is how to make PDA as signer, I tried using #[account(signer)] on top of my pda this way #[account(signer, seeds = [some_seeds], bump)] my_pda: Account<'info, Some_Struct>, but I am getting Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account error although I check the bump is correct

That should be roughly correct, feel free to take a working example and adapt it for your needs, like https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/tree/master/examples/tutorial/basic-3

If you are using Anchor, you can get your program ID from the accounts context using
ctx.program_id

For native programs you have to pass in the program ID, which you can in your process_instruction function
You get this address after building your project with cargo build-sbf command, and getting the public key by reading the deployment keypair in the /target/deploy folder
This is the command to get the public key
solana address -k keypair-file.json


Hi ctx.program_id in program A is returning program A's program_id, although I am calling program A's function with program's B, my question is how to get program B program_id on program A will cpi invoking

you need to pass in the program_id in the accounts struct. No other way of doing this.

and how it can be guaranteed that someone has not passed just program_id as correct and other details as something else, means how can it be validated that the user is authenticated, Program C can be created and program id of B can be passed and for Program A, the call will be coming from Program B?
